# How to rename a file using regex capture group in Linux?

Tags: regex, zsh

I want to rename `a_1.0.tgz` to `b_1.0.tgz`, since `1.0` may be changed to any version number, how can I achieve that?

For example, I can use `mv a*.tgz b.tgz` if I don't need to keep the version number.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*zsh* comes with the utility `zmv`, which is intended for exactly that. While `zmv` does not support regex, it does provide capture groups for filename generation patterns (aka *globbing*).

First, you might need to enable `zmv`. This can be done by adding the following to your `~/.zshrc`:

```
autoload -Uz zmv
```

You can then use it like this:

```
zmv 'a_(*)' 'b_$1'
```

This will rename any file matching `a_*` so, that `a_` is replaced by `b_`. If you want to be less general, you can of course adjust the pattern:

- to rename only `.tgz` files:

  ```
  zmv 'a_(*.tgz)' 'b_$1'
  ```
- to rename only `.tgz` files while changing the extension to `.tar.gz`

  ```
  zmv 'a_(*).tgz' 'b_$1.tar.gz'
  ```
- to only rename `a_1.0.tgz`:

  ```
  zmv 'a_(1.0.tgz)' 'b_$1'
  ```

To be on the save side, you can run `zmv` with the option `-n` first. This will only print, what would happen, but not actually change anything. For more information have a look at the [`man zshcontrib`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#Other-Functions).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too familiar with `zsh` so I don't know if it supports regular expressions but I don't think you really need them here.

You can match the file using a glob and use a substitution:

```
for file in a_[0-9].[0-9].tgz; do 
    echo "$file" "${file/a/b}"
done
```

In the glob pattern, `[0-9]` matches any number between `0` and `9`. `${file/a/b}` substitutes the first occurrence of `a` with `b`.

Change the `echo` to `mv` if you're happy with the result.

Comment: The version number may be like `1.1.1`, not limited to 2 numbers. Is it possible to capture all things after `a` as a group and add this group after `b`?

Comment: You can match whatever you want in the glob (e.g. `a_*.tgz`) and use the same substitution `"${file/a/b}"` to change the letter `a` to `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you would like to replace the first character in all files matching `a*.tgz` with the letter `b`:

```
for f in a*.tgz; do
  echo mv "$f" "b${f:1}"
done
```

Remove the `echo` when you are certain that this does what you want it to do.

The `${f:1}` uses the `${name:offset}` parameter expansion. From the `zshexpn` manual (on OS X):

> If  offset  is  non-negative,  then if the variable name is a
>                 scalar substitute the  contents  starting  offset  characters
>                 from  the  first  character  of the string, [...]